# Rails Multiple Table Inheritance question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starting to implement an MTI solution and have a basic question.  I have 3 physical models - SMSNotifications, EmailNotifications, TwitterNotifications and they are subclasses of notification.  At times in my code, I want to say `Notifications.find(:all)`so that I can get a set of results sorted by their creation time. Then I want to do things based on their subclass.  What is the way to write `Notifications.find(:all)` and have Rails look through the subclass tables and combine the results?  Right now Rails still thinks I have a physical Notifications table which goes against my MTI design.

I am also considering the possibility that I should be using STI instead.  I would probably have 10 empty columns per row but if getting all notifications requires a query for each type of notification, then I feel like this could be a big issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need separate queries for each type.  If this is a dealbreaker, then you should go with either STI or the mixed model approach advocated in your previous question.

Comment: thanks again for your response mike.  i think STI is going to work out better. trying it now...

Answer (score 1):

If you use https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation:

```
rails g model notification notification_type:string notification_id:integer <other columns>
rails g model email_notification <columns>

class EmailNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :notification
end
....
```

then the code you want might be something like this:

```
Notification.all.each do |n|
  case n.notification_type
  when "EmailNotification"
    ...
  when "SMSNotification"
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can make the subclasses have a polymorphic association with some specific model (X). You can edit the callback after_initialize to associate one entry of this specific model X with each of your subclasses on creation. In this way, you can perform find on the target (X) of the mentioned polymorphic association.

Answer (score 0):

I recently forked a promising project to implement multiple table inheritance and class inheritance in Rails. I have spent a few days subjecting it to rapid development, fixes, commenting and documentation and have re-released it as CITIER Class Inheritance and Table Inheritance Embeddings for Rails.

I think it should allow you to do what you needed by asking for all notifications, it will still return the correct models. If you were to do something like

```
Notification.all().each do |n|
  if n.class == 'EmailNotification'
    #Do something
  end
end
```

Or even define a function in the root Notification class and overload it in subclasses to return something different.

Consider giving it a look: http://peterhamilton.github.com/citier

I am finding it so useful! I would (by the way) welcome any help for the community in issues and testing, code cleanup etc! I know this is something many people would appreciate.

Please make sure you update regularly however because like I said, it has been improving/evolving by the day.